# Retornar dados de uma tabela no Web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Desenvolvo uma aplicação, que será implementada em várias empresas, e será preciso fazer alterações da `connectionString` em cada uma delas( pois já possuem servidores instalados, com a base de dados).

Porém, os técnicos que irão realizar a implementação, necessitam de uma forma realizar a conexão com o banco de dados, sem precisar alterar a `connectionString` manualmente.

Para sanar esse problema, inseri uma tabela onde contem os dados da empresa( nome, endereço, etc) e gostaria de saber, se é possível colocar os dados da `connectionString` em alguma tabela, e retornar no valor no **Web.config**( assim os técnicos só terão que preencher o form com a instância, o banco, usuário, etc) configurando assim a `connectionString`.

Comment: Olá, qual a tecnologia de conexão com o banco de dados você está utilizando?  Deixa eu ver se eu entendi. Você vai criar uma tabela no BANCO para falar qual a string de conexão do BANCO para conectar no BANCO e retornar a string que será utilizada para conectar no BANCO?

Comment: Me expressei mal. Não criar uma tabela, e sim alguma forma de salvar esses dados e enviar para minha string de conexão.
Estou utilizando Asp.NET MVC com SQLServer 2008.

Comment: Você quer que a string de conexão altere por usuário sem que ninguém mude?

Comment: Não, apenas oferecer um form, onde o técnico informe o "Server\Instancia" "usuario, Senha", e o "Banco" utilizado. E essas informações fiquem armazenadas em minha connectionString no Web.config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Basta você colocar 4 campos texto para o técnico informar SERVIDOR + BANCO + USUÁRIO + SENHA

E com o conteúdo dos textboxs preencher

```
var section = (ConnectionStringsSection)configuration.GetSection("connectionStrings");
section.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString = "data source="+SERVIDOR+";initial catalog="+BANCO"+;multipleactiveresultsets=True;User ID="+USUARIO"+;Password="+SENHA+";";
```

E para ele nao ter que ficar digitando esses dados a cada login, basta guardar no app.config.

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14744/Read-Write-App-Config-File-with-NET
- https://web.archive.org/web/20200224070230/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/akraus1/archive/2006/01/04/64871.aspx

Um problema parecido com o seu aqui:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719928/how-do-you-modify-the-web-config-appsettings-at-runtime